# Jinja template list and dict parsing

Tags: jinja2, haproxy, salt-stack

I'm trying to get this template to work to create an HAProxy config file. It's almost there, but I can't seem to get the lists in here correctly. I want to save the key and prepend that to the list of items, for example:

This:

```
acl:
  - host_static hdr_beg(host) -i static
  - url_static path_beg static
```

Should be:

```
acl host_static hdr_beg(host) -i static
acl url_static path_beg static
```

This would be any dict key that has a list for their value.

The carryover is there because there could be multiple frontends and backends and those would be a dict under frontend.

I was able to update it, probably a better way to do this, but seems to work ok:

### Edit (Updated Working Code)

```
{%- set key = 0 -%}
{%- set value = 1 -%}
{%- set carryovers = ['frontend', 'backend','listen'] -%}
{%- macro haproxy_config(data, carryover='', listkey='', recurse=-1, indent=0) -%}
  {%- set recurse = recurse + 1 -%}
  {%- if data is none -%}
    {{- '\n' -}}
  {%- elif data is string or data is number -%}
    {{- '%s %s'|format(listkey,data)|string|indent(indent, True) }}{{ '\n' -}}
  {%- else -%}
    {%- if recurse > 0 -%}
      {{- '\n' -}}
      {%- set indent = indent + 2 -%}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- if data is mapping -%}
      {%- for item in data|dictsort -%}
        {%- if item[key] in carryovers -%}
          {{- haproxy_config(item[value], carryover=item[key], indent=indent) -}}
        {%- else -%}
          {%- set carryIndent = indent -%}
          {%- set forwardIndent = indent -%}
          {%- if carryover -%}
            {{- carryover|indent(indent, True) }}{{ ' ' -}}
            {%- set carryIndent = 0 -%}
          {%- endif -%}
          {%- if item[value] is string or item[value] is not iterable -%}
            {%- set forwardIndent = 0 -%}
          {%- endif -%}
          {%- if item[value] is not string and item[value] is iterable and item[value] is not mapping -%}
            {%- set forwardIndent = 0 -%}
            {{ haproxy_config(item[value], listkey=item[key], recurse=recurse, indent=forwardIndent) -}}
          {%- else -%}
            {{- item[key]|indent(carryIndent, True) }} {{ haproxy_config(item[value], recurse=recurse, indent=forwardIndent) -}}
          {%- endif -%}
        {%- endif -%}
      {%- endfor -%}
    {%- else -%}
      {%- for item in data -%}
        {{- haproxy_config(item, listkey=listkey, indent=indent) -}}
      {%- endfor -%}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- if recurse > 0 -%}
      {{ '\n' }}
    {%- endif -%}
  {%- endif -%}
{%- endmacro -%}
```

=======================================================================

### Template:

```
{%- set key = 0 -%}
{%- set value = 1 -%}
{%- set carryovers = ['frontend', 'backend',
      'listen'] -%}
{%- macro haproxy_config(data, carryover='', recurse=-1, indent=0) -%}
  {%- set recurse = recurse + 1 -%}
  {%- if data is none -%}
    {{- '\n' -}}
  {%- elif data is string or data is number -%}
    {{- data|string|indent(indent, True) }}{{ '\n' -}}
  {%- else -%}
    {%- if recurse > 0 -%}
      {{- '\n' -}}
      {%- set indent = indent + 2 -%}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- if data is mapping -%}
      {%- for item in data|dictsort -%}
        {%- if item[key] in carryovers -%}
          {{- haproxy_config(item[value], carryover=item[key], indent=indent) -}}
        {%- else -%}
          {%- set carryIndent = indent -%}
          {%- set forwardIndent = indent -%}
          {%- if carryover -%}
            {{- carryover|indent(indent, True) }}{{ ' ' -}}
            {%- set carryIndent = 0 -%}
          {%- endif -%}
          {%- if item[value] is string or item[value] is not iterable -%}
            {%- set forwardIndent = 0 -%}
          {%- endif -%}
          {{- item[key]|indent(carryIndent, True) }} {{ haproxy_config(item[value], recurse=recurse, indent=forwardIndent) -}}
        {%- endif -%}
      {%- endfor -%}
    {%- else -%}
      {%- for item in data -%}
        {{- haproxy_config(item, indent=indent) -}}
      {%- endfor -%}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- if recurse > 0 -%}
      {{ '\n' }}
    {%- endif -%}
  {%- endif -%}
{%- endmacro -%}
```

### Values

```
haproxy:
  global:
    stats: socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats mode 660 level admin
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers: "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384"
    ssl-default-bind-options: "no-sslv3 no-tlsv10 no-tlsv11"
    user: haproxy
    group: haproxy
    chroot: /var/lib/haproxy
    tune.something.else: 2048
  frontend:
    http:
      bind: 0.0.0.0:80
      option: http-server-close
      acl:
        - host_static hdr_beg(host) -i static
        - url_static path_beg static
      #use_backend: static if host_static
      #use_backend: static if url_static
      default_backend: www
  backend:
    www:
      balance: roundrobin
      #server: www1 www1 check port 80
      #server: www2 www2 check port 80
#      server: www3 www3 check port 80
#      server: load1 localhost:8080 backup
#    static:
#      server: media1 media1 check port 80
#      server: media2 media2 check port 80
#      server: load1 localhost:8080 backup
```

### Output

```
backend www
  balance roundrobin

frontend http
  host_static hdr_beg(host) -i static
  url_static path_beg static
  bind 0.0.0.0:80
  default_backend www
  option http-server-close

global
  chroot /var/lib/haproxy
  daemon True
  group haproxy
  log
    /dev/log local0
    /dev/log local1 notice

  ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
  ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3 no-tlsv10 no-tlsv11
  stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats mode 660 level admin
  tune.something.else 2048
  user haproxy
```

### What I want

```
backend www
  balance roundrobin

frontend http
  acl host_static hdr_beg(host) -i static
  acl url_static path_beg static
  bind 0.0.0.0:80
  default_backend www
  option http-server-close

global
  chroot /var/lib/haproxy
  daemon True
  group haproxy
  log /dev/log local0
  log /dev/log local1 notice

  ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
  ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3 no-tlsv10 no-tlsv11
  stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats mode 660 level admin
  tune.something.else 2048
  user haproxy
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need another section in the if else block `{%- if data is mapping -%}` that checks if it is a list and uses the following.

```
{%- for key, value in data.items() %}
{{key}} {{value}}
{%- endfor %}
```

possibly this

```
{%- set key = 0 -%}
{%- set value = 1 -%}
{%- set carryovers = ['frontend', 'backend',
      'listen'] -%}
{%- macro haproxy_config(data, carryover='', recurse=-1, indent=0) -%}
  {%- set recurse = recurse + 1 -%}
  {%- if data is none -%}
    {{- '\n' -}}
  {%- elif data is string or data is number -%}
    {{- data|string|indent(indent, True) }}{{ '\n' -}}
  {%- else -%}
    {%- if recurse > 0 -%}
      {{- '\n' -}}
      {%- set indent = indent + 2 -%}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- if data is mapping -%}
      {%- for item in data|dictsort -%}
        {%- if item[key] in carryovers -%}
          {{- haproxy_config(item[value], carryover=item[key], indent=indent) -}}
        {%- else -%}
          {%- set carryIndent = indent -%}
          {%- set forwardIndent = indent -%}
          {%- if carryover -%}
            {{- carryover|indent(indent, True) }}{{ ' ' -}}
            {%- set carryIndent = 0 -%}
          {%- endif -%}
          {%- if item[value] is string or item[value] is not iterable -%}
            {%- set forwardIndent = 0 -%}
          {%- endif -%}
          {{- item[key]|indent(carryIndent, True) }} {{ haproxy_config(item[value], recurse=recurse, indent=forwardIndent) -}}
        {%- endif -%}
      {%- endfor -%}
    {%- elif data is iterable and data is not string %}
      {%- for key, value in data.items() %}
        {{- '%s %s'|format(key, value)|indent(indent, True) }}
      {%- endfor %}
    {%- else -%}
      {%- for item in data -%}
        {{- haproxy_config(item, indent=indent) -}}
      {%- endfor -%}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- if recurse > 0 -%}
```

Comment: Let me try that. I wasn't sure how to check for a list as a string is considered a list as well.

Comment: awesome! please upvote and mark it as an answer if it works.

Comment: I don't exactly want to mark this answer as the one since it's not truly the answer if you see my modification above, but it did help me in the right direction. I'm just having another issue now, seems more like a salt bug though.